# how to prevent double counting while counting the bonds between nearest neighbors?

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I am trying to create a n by 2 matrix in which the first column represents the atom indixes and the second column represents the atom indixes in neighbour with the first coulmn' atoms.But I am some how double counting the neighbours.

suppose my matrix looks like

```
 a= [1 2;1 4; 1 6; 2 1; 2 3; 2 5]
```

MY problem is If I have (1 2) in the first row for example, I do not want (2 1) in the 4th row, as it is a repetition of neighbours.

Could you please help me write a piece of code to find the the rows for which (x ,y)==(y, x) and remove one of the rows to prevent double counting.

I want my modified matrix to be like the following for example:

```
  aa=[1 2;1 4; 1 6; 2 3; 2 5]
```

Thank you so much

Comment: It's not entirely clear (to me) how you're making this matrix; but can you require each row to be nondecreasing? Then you would keep $[1 \;\; 2]$ but eliminate $[2 \;\; 1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how I create it is not important here. this is an example. Give n by 2 matrix, I want to search through all the rows and in case I have the swap element of one row in another row, I want to get rid of one of them.

Comment: For $i>j$, if $[i \;\; j]$ is a row, will $[j \;\; i]$ also be a row?

Comment: FYI [tag:coding-theory] is not about programming at all. Rather it is about mathematical methods for example for protecting data from errors during transmission, or methods for turning continuous (or other forms of) data into bits as efficiently as possible.

Comment: @paw88789 No it should not be . thank you for asking